# PHP, MYSQL Nested Queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and Mysql to query a database. What i am trying to do is create the following:

```
Project Name 1
List todo
List todo
List todo 

Project Name 2
List todo
List todo
List todo
```

I have the following mysql tables:

```
Project
project.projectId
project.projectName

Todo
todo.todoId
todo.todoEntry
todo.todoProjectid
```

I can query the table and pull through an entire list of projects and left join the todo. BUT, i want to create a header (Project name) and then underneath do the loop.

I could do a nested sql query for each todo based on the parent but that doesnt sound efficient enough to me. Anyone suggest an improvement?

Comment: Do you mean that 1) retrieve list of projects 2) loop for each project -> query it's todos is not efficient for you, right?

Comment: I mean retrieve the list of projects and for every project collect the todo associated with the project. Currently assigned by the projectid field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made Gordons query a little bit simpler. It now exactly meets your requirements.

```
SELECT
    `name`
FROM 
    (
        (SELECT 'project' as `type`, `name`, `id` as `projectid` FROM `Project`)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT 'todo' as `type`, `name`, `projectid` FROM `Todo`)
    ) as `combined`
ORDER BY
    `project_id`, `type`
```

---

**PHP to get just a list of all rows:**

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT `name` FROM ((SELECT 'project' as `type`, `name`, `id` as `project_id` FROM `projects`) union all (SELECT 'todo' as `type`, `name`, `project_id` FROM `todos`)) as `combined` ORDER BY `project_id`, `type`");

while($row = $q->fetch_object()) {
    echo $row->name . '<br />';
}
```

---

**PHP to get nested lists with 'complicated' query:**

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT `name`, `type` FROM ((SELECT 'project' as `type`, `name`, `id` as `project_id` FROM `projects`) union all (SELECT 'todo' as `type`, `name`, `project_id` FROM `todos`)) as `combined` ORDER BY `project_id`, `type`");

echo '<ul>';

$needToBeClosed = false;

while($row = $q->fetch_object()) {
    if($row->type == 'project' AND $needToBeClosed) {
        echo '</ul></li>';
        $needToBeClosed = false;
    }

    echo '<li>' . $row->name;

    if($row->type == 'project') {
        echo '<ul>';
        $needToBeClosed = true;
    } else {
        echo '</li>';
    }
}

if($needToBeClosed) {
    echo '</ul></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

---

But as you can see, the more you try to do in your query. The more PHP is need to use it in a simple way. So you need to find a balance between SQL and PHP to get the nicest code. I would normally not go for the approach above, but just perform multiple queries like this:

**PHP to get nested list without 'complicated' queries:**

```
$projects = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `projects`');

echo '<ul>';

while($project = $projects->fetch_object()) {
    echo '<li>' . $project->name . '<ul>';
    $todos = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `todos` WHERE `project_id` = ' . $project->id);

    while($todo = $todos->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<li>' . $todo->name . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

---

*You still need to modify the queries for your own needs (table names and such).*

Comment: and what would the php look like?

Comment: I assume you know how to use PHP to fetch a query?

Comment: I have just added all that.

Comment: 'I would normally not go for the approach above, but just perform multiple queries like this'. I am please you said this as i am learning to contain my balance between an efficient query and the number of queries a page loads. How many is too many queries? Would there be any performance issue with nested queries? Its highly unlikely to pull through 1000's of results

Comment: Who would want to see 1000 results on one page? Use pagination or better filters.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have the same columns coming out from the query.  Some are from `Project` and some are from `Todo`.  The challenge is to order them in the right way:

```
select which, name
from ((select 'Project' as which, name, 1 as ordering, projectid, NULL as id
       from  Project p
      ) union all
      (select 'List' as which, entry, 2 as ordering, projectid, id
       from Todo t
      )
     ) t
order by projectid,
         ordering,
         id;
```

Comment: I have edited my text above to remove the duplicate column names. My actual code doesnt have this, i have just done this because it contains sensitive info