# Select from two tables without repeating all the values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Let me clarify myself, my question is "How to select rows from binding single tables and a cross reference table without repeating values?"

Right now I have three tables, a cross reference table and two single tables:

```
           Table jobs
╔══════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ job_id   ║  details                 ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║  1       ║  Looking for hire...     ║
║  2       ║  We need help!...        ║
║  3       ║  We are a store that...  ║
║  4       ║  Help wanted...          ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════════╝

      Table job2pos
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║  job_id   ║ position_id ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║  1        ║  10         ║
║  2        ║  10         ║
║  2        ║  12         ║
║  3        ║  11         ║
║  3        ║  13         ║
║  4        ║  10         ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝

        Table positions
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ position_id   ║ position_name ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║  10           ║  waitress     ║
║  11           ║  cashier      ║
║  12           ║  cook         ║
║  13           ║  chef         ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

When I perform this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT jobs.details, positions.name AS position FROM jobs
INNER JOIN job2pos ON jobs.job_id = job2pos.job_id
INNER JOIN positions ON job2pos.position_id = positions.position_id
WHERE job2pos.job_id IN (2)";
...
print_r($stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

And I get the following:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array ([details] => We need help!...
                [position] => Waitress)
  [1] => Array ([details] => We need help!...
                [position] => Cook)
)
```

Now I got 2 rows for the same job, but what I want is something similar to this:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array ([details] => We need help!...
                [position] => Array ([0] => Waitress
                                     [1] => Cook)
               )
)
```

- If you could point out some unnecessary code I have in my code that would be great.

Comment: try adding  `select distinct jobs.job_id` ?

Comment: You might have to break your query into 2 separate queries. It is working the way it should be.

Comment: @user3360140 Tried, but doesn't work :<

Comment: Try to select the job details first (for id 2) and then as you iterate through the resultset of that query using `foreach` or `while` try to select all positions that match that job.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947131/php-mysql-nested-queries for the case: `PHP to get nested list without 'complicated' queries:`

Comment: AFAIK, you can't get the same exact array format you desire with only mysql, since you need all the position field values, which must come from the query result along with a `details` field value as the results come in rows. (details,position) pairs

Comment: @Maximus2012 The last bit of accepted answer? I'll try to implement that.

Comment: @Maximus2012 After doing some research online, and trying a few things out, your suggestion is probably the best I can find right now.

Comment: Could group by the value that duplicates and [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) the values that vary, although in all honesty, a JSON database is probably better suited to hold these sort of data.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not possible using only one sql-statement. You can think of a result as it would be a table. You can not have any nested information in plain sql.

We have the option of [*nosql*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases to store and retrieve objects.

However, I think what you realy want to have is selecting [`multiple statements with one call`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php).

From the [mysqli documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php):

> MySQL optionally allows having multiple statements in one statement
>   string. Sending multiple statements at once reduces client-server
>   round trips but requires special handling.
>
> Multiple statements or multi queries must be executed with
>   [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php). The individual statements of the statement
>   string are separated by semicolon. Then, all result sets returned by
>   the executed statements must be fetched.
>
> The MySQL server allows having statements that do return result sets
>   and statements that do not return result sets in one multiple
>   statement.

For PDO from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11271707/2441442):

```
$stmt   = $db->query("SELECT 1; SELECT 2;");
$stmt->nextRowset(); //Move to next statement result
var_dump( $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ); //SELCT 2 result
```